# Visual Studio Pro 2010 - Modelling Projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have VS2010 Pro - at my uni I can start a Modelling Project, to plan projects with UML, but here at home the template set isn't there...

Is there something I need to install/do to get this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the architect features in Visual Studio 2010 is only available in the Ultimate Edition. Which version do you have at home ? The Express version does not include UML modelling (other than Class Diagram I believe).

You can see a [comparison diagram here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products). I think the features you are looking for is the Architecture Explorer and "UML® 2.0 Compliant Diagrams (Activity, Use Case, Sequence, Class, Component)", which is only available for Ultimate.

Comment: Hi, I only want the Class Diagram - can't even see that. I have Professional version. Edit: Okay, guess that sucks. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't have Pro installed so I can't test. Modelling Project is not available for Professional, for sure. I am in doubt about the basic class diagram, I think it might be in Professional - you could try to start a new code project and see if you can add a Class Diagram using the Add -> New Item dialog.

Comment: @Motig: Class Diagram is definitely available in the Professional version. I suppose you found it with the help of driis last comment?