# Read modelproj in vs 2013 professional

Tags: visual-studio-2013, uml

I have VS 2013 Ultimate, but some members of the team have VS 2013 Professional. I have created a modeling project, but the VS 2013 Professional versions cannot open it, and receive the error:

Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.

I found this link from MS that indicates the modelproj files can be read by VS Pro.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409445.aspx

Does anyone know if there is an update that needs to be applied?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Professional 2013 should be able to open `Class Diagrams (*.cd)` in read only mode.

It is available as one of the options in the `FILE > Open > File...` menu.

For the rest you are probably out of luck, same as before (see also [Visual Studio Pro 2010 - Modelling Projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422794/visual-studio-pro-2010-modelling-projects)) and you may have to think about a way to deliver your designs and prototypes to the rest of your team in a different way.

Further reading: [MSDN: Visual Studio 2013 → How to: Generate Files from a UML Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee329480.aspx)

---

Disclaimer: I don't know what exactly can the VS Ultimate do as I never really saw it (neither watched a TV trailer) so my answer is in no way complete